# Matching different variables for the same observation

Tags: dataset, stata

I am encountering some difficulty with a dataset that I am analyzing with Stata. The dataset I have is a repeated cross section of the following form:

```
Individual Year Age VarA VarB VarC
```

Variable C has been calculated for each individual by year, using the `egen` command. As a result, this variable is year specific. I now want to match the value of this variable corresponding to the year when each individual was x years old. (I create this new variable by the transform variableD=Year-Age+x).
I want to match the value of Variable C that was obtained in the year "variableD" for each individual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this with a user-written `xfill`:

```
net install xfill, from("http://www.sealedenvelope.com/")
webuse nlswork, clear
duplicates drop idcode age, force
gen x=20 if mod(idcode,2)==1
replace x=25 if mod(idcode,2)!=1
bys idcode year: egen var_c = mean(ln_wage)

bys idcode: gen var_c_at_x = var_c if age == x
xfill var_c_at_x, i(idcode)

edit idcode ln_wage year age x var_c*
```

Comment: Another way to do this is `mipolate, groupwise by()` where `mipolate` is from SSC.